# Calculadora NetBeans - Problemas com operações decimais

Tags: netbeans

Olá, boa noite. Estou tendo que fazer um trabalho de calculadora, e meu código realizava operações como 8+9, 1+7 normalmente, mas não estava fazendo 10+20=3, 50+7=12; o resultado era sempre a soma dos primeiros números. O detalhe de colocar o **inteiro *=10;** e **inteiro += 8;** como na foto ajudou bastante.
[image: inteiro *=10; inteiro += 8;]
Mas por que colocar "**10**" e um asterisco na frente do igual? E um "**+**" na frente do igual no de baixo? E mais uma coisa, agora ela não está efetuando operações decimais. A vírgula até aparece na tela, mas na hora de executar a operação, ele entende que o número é inteiro. Digito **1,1+1** e ele me dá o resultado como **12**. Muito grato, desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `*=` significa que você está fazendo uma operação de multiplicação e atribuindo o resultado para a variável que precede o operador. Dessa forma:

```
inteiro *= 10;
```

**É o mesmo que:**

```
inteiro = inteiro * 10;
```

Quanto ao motivo das operações da sua calculadora não funcionarem como deveriam, sugiro que reveja o seu algoritmo antes de continuar codificando.